# Read dictionary items from a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file dict.txt that include text like this:
Hot Cold
Good Bad
Black White

Below is my code:

```
d = {}
with open('c:\\test\\dict.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[str(key)] = val
        print (d)
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
{'Hot': 'Cold'}
{'Hot': 'Cold', 'Good': 'Bad'}
{'Hot': 'Cold', 'Good': 'Bad', 'Black': 'White'}
```

Why is the list repeating here?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because `print` is _inside_ the `for` loop. Remove 1 level of indent on `print`

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax is indentation-dependent.  Your `print` statement is inside your `for` loop, and this prints with each update of the variable.

**Solution:** Move the `print` statement to outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Not tab dependent, indent dependent. PEP8 recommends 4 spaces, but you can technically use a single space. Tabs are specifically discouraged and decent IDEs convert them to spaces silently

Comment: Thanks alot! it make sense now.

Comment: @ElNana - Excellent.  Please accept this answer and upvote when possible.  Thank you.

Comment: They don't have the reputation to upvote, and nor should they be pushed to do so

Comment: @roganjosh - Thanks for the terminology clarification.  I couldn't think of the right words.  Updated to 'indentation-dependent'.  Thanks.